# How to export the Discussion thread in DevOps user stories and tasks

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking to export the discussion threads inside my user stories and tasks in DevOps. Is there a way to do that through the interface or an extension/plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the discussion records in a specific work item through this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get%20comments?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/comments?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

Here is my sample response(in postman)
[image][image]

If you want to export the response body, you can add the following script to the powershell task to download the response body as a .json file to the local.

```
$strURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/comments?api-version=5.0-preview.2"
$filePath="D:\"
$fileName=$filePath+"\discussion.json"    
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $strURL -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method GET -OutFile $fileName 

Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

[image]

Note: You need to check the option in the figure below.
[image]

Download the sample to the local as follows:
[image]

In addition, discussion comments can't be queried in Queries, so we can't export the discussion through Queries.

Hope this helps.